Why am I getting a Tabulator Data Load Error when AjaxRuesting returns false
I have this data loader table, and when the ajaxRequesting function returns false I get an undefined error logged by the DataLoader.js library: console.error("Data Load Error: ", error);
I'm confused as to why I get a data load error when ajaxRequesting returns false, and it shouldn't attempt to load any data. Any ideas?
  const emailTable = new Tabulator("#email-table", {
    height: "300px",
    columns: [
      { headerSort: false, field: "view", formatter: () => { return EYE_ICON; }, cellClick: viewEmail },
      { headerSort: false, title: "Date", field: "messagedate" },
      { headerSort: false, title: "Author", field: "author" },
      { headerSort: false, title: "Recipient", field: "to" },
      { headerSort: false, title: "Subject", field: "subject" },
      { headerSort: false, title: "CC", field: "cc" },
      { headerSort: false, title: "BCC", field: "bcc" },
      { headerSort: false, title: "Attachments", field: "file_links", formatter: 'html' },
    ],
    dataLoader: true,
    ajaxURL: BASE_URL + '&action=GET_QUERY_RESULTS',
    ajaxConfig: "POST",
    ajaxContentType: {
      body: function (url, config, params) {
        return JSON.stringify({
          queryId: 'GET_SALES_ORDER_MESSAGES',
          params: [JobQueue.salesOrderId]
        });
      },
    },
    ajaxResponse: function (url, params, response) {
      return typeof (response) == 'string' ? JSON.parse(response) : response;
    },
    ajaxRequesting: function (url, params) {
      return validateOrderExists({ notifyUser: false });
    },
  });


